# Unresolved reference to DaggerComponent

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

The code provided bellow still has an Unresolved reference to DaggerAppComponent. I can't find an error.

Already did Rebuild

Here is my Application class

```
class CinemaApplication : SplitCompatApplication() {

    private lateinit var context: Context

    val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(applicationContext)
    }
}
```

Here is my AppComponent class

```
@Component
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(activity: NavHostActivity)
}
```

Here is my Activity class

```
class NavHostActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        (application as CinemaApplication).appComponent.inject(this)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
```

Comment: In the Line DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(applicationContext) did you try to change "applicationContext to MainActivity.class(for example) or use getapplicationcontext()

Comment: @RubenMeiring getapplicationcontext() = applicationcontext in Kotlin world.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843996/android-kotlin-error-unresolved-reference-daggerappcomponent Maybe something here could help you

Answer (score 1):

Try using `kapt`

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.22"
}
```

Comment: Please add your gradle file also

Comment: Also try with `invalidate cache and restart` in AS